# What's wrong with this code?

Tags: apex

```
string contactId = '003N000001cUWnpIA';
Contact cnt = [select id from Contact where id : contactId][0];
system.debug(cnt);
```

I've got error
Line: 2, Column: 9
Unexpected token 'cnt'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `=` sign before the `:`.

See the below code should work.

```
string contactId = '003N000001cUWnpIA';
Contact cnt = [select id from Contact where id = :contactId][0];
system.debug(cnt);
```

Refer [Using Apex Variables in SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)

Comment: Personally, from a layout perspective, I feel the ":" should be attached to the binding variable name, not the operator. The colon indicates that the following name is the name of a binding variable. It has nothing to do with the operator being applied.

Comment: @PhilW Seems a good idea, thanks!!

Comment: @PhilW I strongly agree.